# Проксирование трафика

Tags: tcp-ip, proxy, трафик, debian

Есть две рабочие машины. Есть еще 1 машина под фильтрами(ОС везде Debian)Рабочие машины должны быть связаны с сетью, так сложилось что фильтры на них подцеплять слишком дорого, а брать другие то же, не очень хороший вариант.У машины под фильтром самый жирный канал, хотел бы чтобы трафик проходил через нее, с сохранением всех данных( IP адресов клиентов), баловался с IPTABLES.. Может посоветуете еще какие либо средства для подобных задач?

Comment: Что такое "фильтры"?

Comment: аппаратные фильтры трафика, защита от DDOS атак, по русски говоря.

Answer (score 1):

Советую и дальше продолжать баловаться с iptables.

А почему ищите другие средства, что не удалось сделать с помощью iptables?

Comment: нужен IP клиента

Answer (score 0):

Хм. На ум приходит Squid.

Comment: Мне не нужен http прокси, трафик у меня разных ходит.

Comment: Например какой? Просто уточнение, чтобы понять, что может подойти для такой задачи.

Comment: tcp обычный софт работающий на сокетах